# How to override ubuntu shortcuts when using RubyMine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, rubymine

I can't find an answer to this anywhere, please help. I am using RubyMine IDE on Ubuntu 14.04 and what really bugs me is that I can't use some of the RubyMine shortcuts, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, which opens the terminal instead and similar ones. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't override the system shortcuts, but you can remap shortcuts in RubyMine to avoid shortcuts conflicts. See Settings | Keymap